# Replacing outlier with second minimum value group by in R

Tags: r, data.table, outliers

I am new to R, I have a data.table dt

```
> library(data.table)
> dt <- data.table(A = c(1,2,3,4,74,6, 7, 8, 9, 75, 11, 12), 
+                  B=c("P","P","P","P", "P", "P" ,"Q","Q","Q", "Q", "Q", "Q"), 
+                  C=c("a","b","c","d","e","f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l"))
> dt
     A B C
 1:  1 P a
 2:  2 P b
 3:  3 P c
 4:  4 P d
 5: 74 P e
 6:  6 P f
 7:  7 Q g
 8:  8 Q h
 9:  9 Q i
 10: 75 Q j
 11: 11 Q k
 12: 12 Q l
```

I computed the outlier in the values of A, with standard deviation using following

```
> #Outlier Identification by customer_count
> dt[,out := ifelse((A > (mean(A)+2*sd(A))|A < (mean(A)-2*sd(A))),1,0) ]
> dt
     A B C out
 1:  1 P a   0
 2:  2 P b   0
 3:  3 P c   0
 4:  4 P d   0
 5: 74 P e   1
 6:  6 P f   0
 7:  7 Q g   0
 8:  8 Q h   0
 9:  9 Q i   0
10: 75 Q j   1
11: 11 Q k   0
12: 12 Q l   0
```

The column "out" indicates my outlier, Now I want to replace that outlier value in A, with the second minimum value by each group by "B". How can I do this.

My final outcome should look like:

```
> dt
     A B C out
 1:  1 P a   0
 2:  2 P b   0
 3:  3 P c   0
 4:  4 P d   0
 5:  2 P e   1
 6:  6 P f   0
 7:  7 Q g   0
 8:  8 Q h   0
 9:  9 Q i   0
10:  8 Q j   1
11: 11 Q k   0
12: 12 Q l   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do with `replace`

```
dt[, A := replace(A, out ==1, sort(A)[2]) , by = B]
dt
#     A B C out
# 1:  1 P a   0
# 2:  2 P b   0
# 3:  3 P c   0
# 4:  4 P d   0
# 5:  2 P e   1
# 6:  6 P f   0
# 7:  7 Q g   0
# 8:  8 Q h   0
# 9:  9 Q i   0
#10:  8 Q j   1
#11: 11 Q k   0
#12: 12 Q l   0
```

---

Or another option is

```
dt[, A := pmax((out==1)*sort(A)[2], (out==0)*A), B]
```

Comment: There seems to be a partial sorting option in `?sort` that might be worth using for a case like this.